# Is there any way to reverse encrypted captcha to plain text

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption

I am writing a small software to extract text from website. but there is encrypted captcha available there. I want to decrypt that in my c# program and bypass that. here is encrypted captcha found on that page and corresponding plain captcha.

Encrypted captcha :

```
VFRZWVdLYlRpSUpXN1ZDdU1BcDZiK0lOWFdCTFNtM2cxZFRqb0dlR0txZnlmWHJ2U01OV0hFeW5FYm1YNUloR3JPdHhQaHBFT2tsbwpJbmlSbkxzNmdPblVGc1N0UmdnZDQxVUNHYlJseXFGRkE1d1o5ODNuSGc9PQ==
```

Output plain text captcha is: 8RTE9

Is there any way by which I can guess algorithm used in this encryption?

Comment: Why would you implement a captcha if it can easily be read by a machine?

Comment: I understand that part. but I have been told to do this at my job. so need this .. any idea or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: It wouldn't be very good "encryption" if you could easily decrypt it.  And if it's a hash value it may not be decryptable at all.  (Which seems likely to me.)  Either way, if you want to know how someone's captcha works, you're probably going to have to ask them.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA#Circumvention

Comment: Thanks for quick response David , If it is hash value then what is the use of this field in post parameter. I recorded in fiddler.

Comment: @mitesh It's probably used by the web app to verify that once hashed, the value provided by the user is equal to this value, thus allowing validation without having the captcha in the document

Comment: The entire point of using a captcha is to prevent what you are attempting to do.

Comment: @mitesh: It would probably be used to compare it with the hash of the entered value.  Much like a password.  Though, again, you would really need to ask whoever maintains that site if you want to know the specifics of how they've implemented something.  All we can do is randomly guess.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a game of "guess that implementation".

Comment: If you are trying to subvert the wishes of the content provider you are morally wrong! But I guess you know that and that is not important to you.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to this is you can't.

Not using the method you want to use anyway.

The reason captcha exists is to prevent machines from performing automated login or just to verify that the user is actually a human.

You're not going to be able to decrypt a captcha on the client side. Chances are the captcha processing is done entirely on the server side.

The encryption keys aren't available to you and to 'guess' (brute force) the encryption key will likely take conventional hardware until after the heat death of the universe. That's if captcha even uses encryption. It might use hashing instead (which is more likely).

As for identifying the encryption/hashing algorithm used? If you can work out what captcha library is being used you MAY be able to figure out if it uses default values and use that as a baseline for creating a data set for machine learning. Again, these are big IFS and BUTS.

If it's an open source captcha library then it's possible you could use machine learning to circumvent the captcha by generating a training set for a machine learning algorithm using the library.

Of course ultimately you should tell your boss at the company you work at that you can't do this. Years of research and probably hundreds of thousands or millions of dollars have gone into creating this kind of technology to prevent people from being able to do exactly what you're suggesting you need to do.